# .NET Core inject options and change the value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have .NET Core app. In controller I have:

```
private readonly IOptions<WopiOptions> _wopiOptions;

public HomeController(IOptions<WopiOptions> wopiOptions)
{
    _wopiOptions = wopiOptions;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var siteName = HttpContext.GetSiteName();
    var tenant = await _commonRepository.GetTenantAsync(siteName);
    var wopiOptions = _wopiOptions.Value;
    wopiOptions.HostPageDomain = wopiOptions.HostPageDomain.Replace(":sitename", tenant.SiteName.ToLower());

    model.OldWopiOptions = _wopiOptions.Value.HostPageDomain;
    model.WopiOptions = wopiOptions.HostPageDomain;

    return View(model);
}
```

WopiOptions into appsettings.json:

```
"Wopi": {
    "HostPageDomain": "https://:sitename.domain.com"
}
```

And I expect in model:

```
_wopiOptions.Value.HostPageDomain = "https://:sitename.domain.com" always
wopiOptions.HostPageDomain = "https://myrealsitename.domain.com" so it replaces with appropriate data
```

But actual I see `https://myrealsitename.domain.com` in both cases.
So first logged in user replaced the value with "myrealsitename" and after I log in with another user I see old "myrealsitename".
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong here?" - modifying `IOptions` values, you are not supposed to do it. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chould check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0#options-interfaces)  related

`IOptions<TOptions>` is registed as  Singleton once you modified it in the first request,you would get the modified value in the next request

If you want get the original value `"https://:sitename.domain.com"` in another request,`IOptionsSnapshot<TOptions>` would work for you

[image]